# js commands in Google Chrome Console won't work anymore o_0

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There is something strange going on with my `Google Chrome Dev Tools`.
`var` or `for` just thrown an `undefined` error.
I.e. just simple

```
var a=1;
```

Throws an error. Can't get what is wrong.
All my scripts was working just fine a month ago.
Is this some new update or any settings problem?
Can't google nothing similar. What settings is worth to check?
Screenshot included.
[image: Chrome Console gone mad]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I mean: can you use the variable 'a' or do you get an error message when you try to do that? oO
Because the 'undefined' that's printed in the console is just the return value from a 'var' assignment call, nothing to be worried about.

Comment: any of my js scripts not work anymore.
like, i don't know. 
try
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}

Comment: Like

http://take.ms/T0xFp

Comment: I just did: the for-loop you mentioned in the comment is working perfectly well, printing the numbers 0 through 9 and returning undefined. How about you post some code that's actually not doing what it's supposed to?

Comment: Ok, this script is working for you? http://take.ms/TQVIE

Comment: Yes it is, however: i changed the console filter to 'error' and than the log output is not shown... seems like you just need to change that setting back to normal in the dev tools('info' seems to be the default choice?).

Answer (score 2):

This is correct behavior.

`var a = 1` [is a statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), not an expression, so it doesn't return a value.

`a = 1`, on the other hand, [is an expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators), which returns 1. This is why you can do stuff like this:

```
a = b = c = 1

// is the same as:

c = 1
b = c
a = b
```

Comment: @PavelKostin: That's working fine - a `for` loop is a statement, so that should loop 10 times (doing nothing each time, since you've left the body empty) then return `undefined` in the console. What are you expecting?

Comment: @PavelKostin: Looking at your other comments, I think you're misunderstanding how the console works - `var x = 1` doesn't return `1`, it *sets* `x` on the global scope. You can get the value of `x` simply by typing `x` into the console.

Comment: I used to write few complicated scripts some time ago.

Comment: @PavelKostin: Ah, another issue - you have your console filters set to 'Errors', so it's not showing any `console.log` output. Change the dropdown at the top of the console (next the 'filter' text box) to 'Info'.